# How to get jquery dialog position on dragStop event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

In my application I have requirement as below:
When a user clicks on menu item a jquery dialog opens by default on the top left side of browser. If user drags dialog box to some place on window and opens another menu item, the dialog box is automatically getting placed on top left side of page. But, I want to show new item click dialog box in position where previous dialog box drag stopped. For that I tried to save the left and top position values on dragstop event of dialog box but, its not showing the top and left values after dialog box drag, instead it is showing default top left values.
My code:

```
$("#modalDiv").dialog({
  position: {
    my: "left top",
    at: "left top+122",
    of: "body"
  },
  beforeClose: function(event, ui) {
    alert('Firing close- top:' + $(this).position().top + "  left:" + $(this).position().left);
  },
  dragStop: function(event, ui) {
    //This alert message should show latest top left postion values of jquery dialog box it is showing default top left values even after drag event finished?

    //alert('Firing close- top:' + $(this).position().top + "  left:" + $(this).position().left);
  }
}).dialog("open").parent().appendTo(jQuery('form:first')).find('.ui-dialog-title').html('<span>' + titleStr + '</span>');
```

Any help to solve it is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a dialog, jQuery internally represents it using a `div` element. You can observe the property `aria-describedby` of that div as it contains the same ID as of the dialog, and get its position:

```
$("[aria-describedby= modalDiv]").position();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this way but position is an object([object Object]) now. when I tried to see the properties left and right (like position.left and position.right) values it shows as undefined in alert messag